# Add response headers if a request was served via proxy with `http-server`

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-proxy, httpserver

How can I add a specific response header when the response was served via the proxy instead of directly?
The reason for adding the response header is basically just that I want to find out whether the response came via proxy or it came directly.

This is how I'm creating the server currently:

```js
const httpServer = require('http-server');
const server = httpServer.createServer({
    gzip: true,
    proxy: 'https://proxy.target.url',
    https: {
        key: './key.pem',
        cert: './cert.pem'
    },
});
```

This will create a server so it proxies all requests which can't be resolved locally to the given URL.

How can I have the server mark the proxied responses(i.e. responses that were received through `https://proxy.target.url`)?

Comment: Do you control the proxy? Can the proxy send you a secret only you recognize?

Comment: @Evert No, I don't control the proxy.

Comment: Do you know what IP addresses they use? Do you have _anything_ that uniquely idenfies it? If the answer is no, and you're trying to detect *any* proxy then there's no easy way to do this. It's hard to detect vpns/proxies if they don't want to be found.

Comment: @Evert I'm not trying to detect _any_ proxy. I just want to detect whether my response went through the proxy server identified by the proxy attribute I specify in the object I pass to `createServer`.
I am looking for a solution that adds a header or something to indicate that the response went through the proxy(i.e. through `https://proxy.target.url` in the code in this question).

Comment: Edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Ah so you _do_ control the proxy. The issue here might be that you're using an 'off the shelf quick HTTP proxy server', that doesn't allow for a lot of customization. You might need to use something that has a few more options such as middlewares.